# Dropping outliers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I've tried to drop outliers by definining a condition but it doesn't work correctly.Here's the outliers.

[image]

Then I tried to drop those rows using this.

```
print(np.where(dataframe['Generosity']>0.4))
```

and the output was only two rows.It not showing 3rd outlier.

```
(array([ 81,  97, 122], dtype=int64),)
```

I tried to drop above rows and generate the new box plot. But one outlier is still there.

```
dataframe=dataframe.drop([81,97,122,])
sb.boxplot(dataframe['Generosity'])
```

[image]

Comment: What about using `showfliers=False`?

Comment: This is not the same outlier. This new outlier is relative to the new population. Check the duplicate for a detailed explanation ;)

Comment: .... which is why you can turn off showing the outliers with `showfliers`, w/o changing the population.

Comment: When you drop outliers the calculation of outliers adjusts to the data without the previous outliers and new outliers may turn up.

Comment: In here it's just a plain CSV with the data. I haven't used any calculation so far.